# Better way to write this `function calculate()`

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code used to calculate an equation based on user input from a text field.
Equation is: **((a * b) + (b * c)) / (a + b)**

I am wondering if there is another way to do the same thing more simpler, shorter, nicer, etc

HTML

```
<div id="calculusB">
    <p style="font-size: 25px; color: #d81cbc;">Please calculate:</p>
    <img src="formula.jpg" style="margin-left: 94px"> <br>
    Enter "a" here: <input style="margin-top: 50px;" type="text" id="a" placeholder="a" name="a" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event)"><br>
    Enter "b" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="text" id="b" placeholder="b" name="b" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event)"><br>
    Enter "c" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="text" id="c" placeholder="c" name="c" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event)"><br>
    <input style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 140px" type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" onclick="return calculate();">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function calculate() {
  var valA = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var actualA = parseInt(valA);
  var valB = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var actualB = parseInt(valB);
  var valC = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var actualC = parseInt(valC);
  var par1 = actualA * actualB;
  var par2 = actualB * actualC;
  var denominator = actualA + actualB;
  var numerator = par1 + par2;
  var result =  numerator / denominator;
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a code review request.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fine by me. I did not realize there is another place to post questions like this. I'm quite new on platform. If there is anybody who can move it in the right place, I'm OK with this and I regret that this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery makes DOM queries simpler. It's almost a must for any web development.

To import, add this line at the beginning of your `<script>` tag in your HTML file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can write in your Javascript file:

```
function calculate() {
  var a = parseInt($("#a").val());
  var b = parseInt($("#b").val());
  var c = parseInt($("#c").val());
  var result = ((a * b) + (b * c)) / (a + b);
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I am planning to learn JQuery after I master well JS, I am going to accept your answer. All guys answered like I wanted but your method is the most probably to try it.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite good, just some tips:

use `<input type="number" />` to avoid `parseInt()`

and you can simplify your function

```js
function calculate() {
  var actualA = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var actualB = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var actualC = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var result =  ((actualA * actualB) + (actualB * actualC)) /(actualA + actualB);
  alert(result);
}
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="calculusB">
  <p style="font-size: 25px; color: #d81cbc;">Please calculate:</p>
  <img src="formula.jpg" style="margin-left: 94px"> <br>
  Enter "a" here: <input style="margin-top: 50px;" type="number" id="a" placeholder="a" name="a"><br>
  Enter "b" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="number" id="b" placeholder="b" name="b"><br>
  Enter "c" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="number" id="c" placeholder="c" name="c"><br>
  <input style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 140px" type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" onclick="return calculate();">
</div>
```

Comment: there's a missing parentheses `((actualA * actualB) + (actualB * actualC))`

Comment: thanks will change it

Comment: @messerbill Thank you very much for your answer. At this time I don't want to use `number` because of the little arrows in the input field (I believe they are called spinners). I just don't like them in this situation. 
Anyway, your answer did improve my code. I wasn't aware that I can write the whole formula :D so I splitted it out.

Comment: @Catalin I added some css to remove the arrows. I guess this is better than using `type="text"` ;)

Comment: @messerbill WOW :) In this case, yes, this is the best way. Thanks!

Comment: so please mark the answer with the green hook to mark it solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution which I find it more simple to read
what i have done is to change the the input type into number so that we can avoid testing if the value is number or not

```js
function calculate() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var result = ((a * b)+(b * c)) / (a + b);
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<div id="calculusB">
  <p style="font-size: 25px; color: #d81cbc;">Please calculate:</p>
  Enter "a" here: <input style="margin-top: 50px;" type="number" id="a" placeholder="a" name="a" /></br> Enter "b" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="number" id="b" placeholder="b" name="b" /></br>
  Enter "c" here: <input style="margin-top: 5px;" type="number" id="c" placeholder="c" name="c" /></br>
  <input style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 140px" type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" onclick="calculate();" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I said to @messerbill I don't want to use `number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your HTML by using setting the `type` to `number` which means that you don't have to rely on a separate function to validate the input. You can use a button to submit the calculation to the function.

```
<div id="calculusB">
  <p class="label">Please calculate:</p>
  <input type="number" placeholder="a"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="b"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="c"><br>
  <button>Calculate</button>
</div>
```

Note that all the in-line JS has been removed from the HTML too. That's because you can use JS to pick up the elements and, in the case of the button, add an event listener to it.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', calculate, false);
```

Finally your code can be simplified with some ES6 flair:

```
function calculate() {

  // Take the input elements, `map` over them and return
  // the parsed value, and deconstruct them into the a, b, and c variables
  const [a, b, c] = [...inputs].map(input => Number(input.value));

  // Simply reconstruct the formula using the variables
  const out = ((a * b) + (b * c)) / (a + b);
  console.log(out);
}
```

Here's the working demo:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', calculate, false);

function calculate() {
  const [a, b, c] = [...inputs].map(input => Number(input.value));
  const out = ((a * b) + (b * c)) / (a + b);
  console.log(out);
}
```

```css
.label {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #d81cbc;
}

input[type="number"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculusB">
  <p class="label">Please calculate:</p>
  <input type="number" placeholder="a"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="b"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="c"><br>
  <button>Calculate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is a little to much for me right now since I am very beginner in HTML, CSS and JS. You outlined probably the next step for me in learning, but after JS and after JQuery (or other library - anyway, I'm not familiar with none of them) are well fixed. Until then I will try to fix these simple methods.
But this is what I wanted, other ways to write the same code, so thank you for your answer.